# High-level, functional or object-oriented language or platform with isolation from OS

Tags: security, operating-system, isolation

I'm searching for a language which gives some basic features like the most popular languages like Python, C#, JavaScript, so math operations, string manipulation, object access and transformations, serialization, but has something like isolated execution environment by default, so you cannot access OS layer directly or easily with the language.

If talking about mentioned - let's take C# - you can access OS with .NET Framework. JavaScript executed on Node - `spawn` function, Python - `os.system` or `subprocess.call` etc.

How about a language in which you cannot do this by default - we are not considering exploits here or other hacking approaches, just pure language, but maybe there is a special language in which it's hard to make some exploits by default.

The other option maybe there is a special platform for existing language which prevent OS access.

Comment: What's the end goal you want to achieve?

Comment: Javascript cannot do IO outside a web browser without explicit permission from a user. Node.js is actually a server software that runs js server side before sending html to the client. From Wikipedia: ```Node.js lets developers use JavaScript to write command line tools and for server-side scripting. The functionality of running scripts server-side produces dynamic web page content before the page is sent to the user's web browser.```